# change sql into HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have below sql statement

```
select items.id, ((sum(today.view_cnt) - sum(yesterday.view_cnt)) as point
from items
left outer join stats yesterday 
on items.id = yesterday.items_id
and yesterday.base_date>='2013-05-29' and yesterday.base_date < '2013-05-30'
left outer join stats today   
on items.id = today.items_id

and today.base_date >='2013-05-29' and today.base_date < '2013-05-30'
group by items.id
having sum(yesterday.view_cnt) >150
order by point desc
```

---

I want to change this into HQL statement. 
Some of them I don't know how I can change into HQL.

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Stats.class, "seriesStats");

Criteria itemCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("items", "items", RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("items.id", ???? ));   ---->
```

// I want to make sql query as below 
// left outer join stats yesterday on items.id = yesterday.items_id

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections
            .projectionList()
            .add(Projections.???????)  --> 

             ((sum(today.view_cnt) - sum(yesterday.view_cnt)) as point


            .add(Projections.groupProperty("items.id")));
```

Otherwise, should I use 'query' instead of 'Criteria'?
I wonder how I should change sql statement into Criteria or Query?
Please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: You're not trying to convert to HQL but to Hibernate criteria right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session.createSQLQuery("native sql query")` to fire pure native sql in `hibernate`.

for reference

[link1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

[link2](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/)